# How to delete part of a URL using Greasemonkey?

Tags: url, redirect, greasemonkey

I'm trying to make a Greasemonkey script that passes me from this:

```
http://redirector/referal_ID:site#link
```

to this:

```
link
```

In other words, I need to delete the first part of the links that I click on, bypassing the redirector pages `http://redirector/referal_ID:site#` and keep only what is after the # character the **link**.

Note that **redirector** changes frequently, **referal_id** is always unique and different, and `site#` is the only constant string in all of the links.

I've tried to modify various scripts but my, next to null, knowledge of javascript foils all my attempts.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------**

An example of what I need to do is to modify this:

```
http://firstfirst.net/identi_ref?q=Waterfox%2033.0.2%20[Mozilla%20Firefox%20de%2064%20bits]&ref=http://www.identi.li/c#https://shared.com/dhq1l9djj1?s=l
```

into this:

```
https://shared.com/dhq1l9djj1?s=l
```

The site where I want the script to work is `http://www.identi.li/`

Comment: What's one example of a script you tried to modify? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @nathan-tuggy  This is a section of the last example code that I tried to modify `// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var links,thisLink;
links = document.evaluate("//a[@href]",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
for (var i=0;i<links.snapshotLength;i++) {
    var thisLink = links.snapshotItem(i);

    thisLink.href = thisLink.href.replace('http://stackoverflow.com/',
                                          'http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
}`

Comment: You have substantially changed the question. Are you trying to redirect the page or change a bunch of links on it?

Comment: @BrockAdams When I click on the link, the longer one, I want to ignore all of the address up until the # character, where the true link begins, thus bypassing the redirection forced by the long link, which includes unwanted adware and/or spyware.

Answer (score 1):

The trickiest part of this is making sure the script does not fire on pages that are not redirectors. To do that, use a [regex `@include`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Regular_Expressions).

After that, it's just a matter of extracting the target site and changing the `location`. Here's a complete script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Skip redirects
// @include     /site#http/
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var targetSite = location.href.replace (/^.+?site#(http.+)$/, "$1");

//--- Use assign() for debug or replace() to keep the browser history clean.
location.assign (targetSite);
//location.replace (targetSite);
```

---

Note that the `@run-at document-start` is not strictly necessary, but it can shave the response time, of a redirect script, by a fair amount.

Comment: Not sure what @grant is in there for. I was assuming to make sure the script is executed in semi-chrome privileges, but that shouldn't normally make a difference.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, You're right.  The grant is an old (good) habit, I forgot to delete from my base GM script template in this case. For this, it doesn't matter.  But get in the habit of scripting with the sandbox on, or it will bite you in the {censored} some day.

Comment: Fair enough. I normally do `//@grant GM_log` for that though if I'm not sure it's fine to run in page, at least when I'm not using `GM_getValue` or something (which is most of the time).

Comment: @NathanTuggy, [`GM_log` is deprecated](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_log) and may be removed from future versions of Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey, etc.